# How to wire to an existing Wall Outlet

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am hanging a TV in my bedroom and I need power from an outlet that is directly below my TV Wall Box where I can plug the TV in and pass other wires. The issue is that even though I drilled a 1" hole in the stud, and can pass wire down to the existing box, there is no way to get the wire into the box because there isnt a hole to do so.
Attached are some pictures.
Do I need to remove the existing box or can I just kill the power and drill a new hole in the top to pass the wire through?
What would be better?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There should be a passage in the top or bottom of the existing junction box to let a cable in. They may be all full on the top.

But you're going to need something else to fish the signal cables down.  They can't mix with AC power.  So you might as well open up the wall just to the left of the box, or above the box, go give an exit for data cables.  Note that the cable jack may be in an "old work" box clipped to the drywall, and drywall is literally chalk wrapped in paper, so it's not like it has any strength.  Don't undercut the drywall the other box needs to hang onto.